# How to get final redirect of a URL with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have the URL `https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?id=286238429359299` which gets redirected to `https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=political_and_issue_ads&country=US&impression_search_field=has_impressions_lifetime&id=286238429359299&view_all_page_id=575939395898200` in the browser.

I'm using the following code:

```
    @Test
    public void createWebClient() throws IOException {
        getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(OFF);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(CHROME);
        WebClientOptions options = webClient.getOptions();
        options.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        options.setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
        // IMPORTANT: Without the country/language selection cookie the redirection does not work!
        URL s = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?id=286238429359299").getUrl();
    }
```

The above code doesn't take into account of the redirection, is there something I am missing? I need to get the final URL the original URL resolves to.

Comment: As the answers have noted, the "final" URL depends on who and how the URL is requested. There may not be a single _final_ URL.

Answer (score 0):

actually the url https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?id=286238429359299 return a page with javascript.The javascript will detect environment of the  web browser.For example,the js will detect if the current browser is the Headless browser and if the web driver is legal.So I think the solution is to analysis the javascript and you will get the final url.

Answer (score 0):

I think it never actually resolves to final URL due being headless.

Please load the same page in a browser, load the source code and search for "page_uri" and you will see exactly URI you are looking for.

If you would check HtmlUnit output or print the page

```
 System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

You will see that "page_uri" contains originally entered URL.
I suggest to use Selenium WebDriver (not headless)